# Cannot launch GUI with startx: Module i915 not found

Tags: linux-mint, xorg

I  have installed Linux Mint version 18 on my PC. In the past, I have been able to get the desktop to launch by typing

> startx

at the terminal. After I did a few upgrades, this command stopped working. I get an error message

modprobe: FATAL: Module i915 not found in directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-145-generic

Fatal server error: (EE) no screens found (EE)

I am not sure what this means. I browsed the web and I guess it has something to do with the Intel Graphics driver.

Comment: i915 is one of the kernel modules for the Intel Graphics. There have been changes in what kernel module was preferred for certain hardware, so likely your "few upgrades" broke a configuration somewhere. 1) Make sure to install the newest kernel. 2) Remove any `xorg.conf` (probably in `/etc/X11`, but I'm not that familiar with Mint). If you have it customized, create a new one, with the current preferred driver. 3) In doubt, look at `/var/log/Xorg.0.log`, for details about what X is trying to do, and why it fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i915 is one of the kernel modules for the Intel Graphics. There have been changes in what kernel module was preferred for certain hardware, so likely your "few upgrades" broke a configuration somewhere.

1) Make sure to install the newest kernel.

2) Remove any xorg.conf (probably in /etc/X11, but I'm not that familiar with Mint). If you have it customized, create a new one, with the current preferred driver.

3) In doubt, look at /var/log/Xorg.0.log, for details about what X is trying to do, and why it fails.